# how to make iOS 7 UIScrollView suppress touch events on embedded UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uievent

Think of a `UIScrollView` with embedded (subview) `UIView`s, arranged in a column. In iOS6 and previously, the scroll view could be configured so that when you flick it with your finger, the embedded views do not receive touch events even if the initial touch is on one of the subviews; but if you touch a subview without flicking, the scroll view decides this is not a scroll action and forwards the touch events to the embedded views. This was very convenient behavior if you wanted to be able to drag/drop the embedded `UIView`s within the `UIScrollView`.

In iOS 7 the documentation indicates that setting the `UIScrollView` property `delaysContentTouches` will cause touch-down events to be delayed until the `UIScrollView` decides whether it's being scrolled. But in fact, this simply does not appear to work. The subview immediately receives touch events and responds to them if the scrolling touch-down event is on one of the subviews. Thus if the subview is programmed for drag/drop it starts dragging while the scroll view also scrolls.

It appears that the model for this behavior has been changed, since iOS 5/6 both did suppress touch events while deciding whether this is a scroll action. Some new methods are now available to cancel the touch-down events after the `UIScrollView` decides it is scrolling. But obviously this is not useful if the drag/drop code has also started moving the subview.

My question: Is there any way to prevent iOS 7 `UIScrollView`s from invoking low-level touch-down events on its subviews, when you initiate a scrolling action by stroking a subview? 
When I say "low-level", I mean actual touch events as opposed to using gesture recognizers. I am convinced that simply setting the `delaysContentTouches` property to YES does not work.

This problem has totally busted some quite complex code that worked smoothly and beautifully in iOS 5 and 6; and, so far I have discovered no way to tell the `UIScrollView` to suppress events to its subviews until it determines whether or not it is being scrolled. The events go through, then a cancellation touch event is triggered later, after the scroll view determines it is scrolling. It looks like the underlying model has been redefined for the worse, or this is a bug. Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it was working on iOS5/6? Based on my experience and posts like [UIScrollview delaysContentTouches issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701323/uiscrollview-delayscontenttouches-issue) it doesn't work.

Maybe a sample code which shows it working on iOS5/6 but not on iOS7 will help to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
[scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
```