# Find UIGestureRecognizer action (selector) name and target

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uikit

I'm trying to find which action is triggered by a UIGestureRecognizer on which target. Unfortunately there is no property on a `UIGestureRecognizer` such as `gesture.action` or `gesture.target`. The gesture I'm analyzing is part of UIKit private implementation.

**Partial Answer here**

[stackOverFlow Question 20066315](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240634/getting-the-action-of-uigesturerecognizer-in-ios)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a code snippet that will list all target/action pairs associated with a gesture recognizer:

```
Ivar targetsIvar = class_getInstanceVariable([UIGestureRecognizer class], "_targets");
id targetActionPairs = object_getIvar(gesture, targetsIvar);

Class targetActionPairClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIGestureRecognizerTarget");
Ivar targetIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(targetActionPairClass, "_target");
Ivar actionIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(targetActionPairClass, "_action");

for (id targetActionPair in targetActionPairs)
{
    id target = object_getIvar(targetActionPair, targetIvar);
    SEL action = (__bridge void *)object_getIvar(targetActionPair, actionIvar);

    NSLog(@"target=%@; action=%@", target, NSStringFromSelector(action));
}
```

Note that you'll have to import `<objc/runtime.h>`, and that this uses private ivars and a class, so it could get you banned from the App Store.

Comment: Would it be possible to capture the value of navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer._targets using KVC and apply it to a pan gesture recogniser?

Answer (score 0):

I have a different solution to this which has worked for me.  This is more of a design change... you cannot access the target from the captured gesture.  So instead keep a reference to the object when the touch down happened and before the pan began.

```c
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *myTouchedButton; // reference to button

(void)init
{
    ...
    [card.button addTarget:self action:@selector(cardTouchDownInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    ...
}

-(void)cardTouchDownInside:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"touch down on object");
    self.myTouchedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
}
```