# Remove a UITapGestureRecognizer from a view without having a strong pointer to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` (TapGes) on the `UIWindow` with target on a `UIViewController` (vc).

I don't and I can't have a strong pointer to TapGes from vc. 
So after certain time vc is going to dealloc (when its done) and at this point I would like to remove TapGes from the UIWindow but I haven't found a way to do so.

If it was a view I would do something like:

1. Set a Tag to that view
2. Iterate on `UIWindow` subviews
3. Find the `UIView` with that tag
4. Remove it from superview

The problem is that `UITapGestureRecognizer` does not have a way of identify it like tag.

Is there a solution to this problem with the conditions:

- Not having a strong pointer to `UITapGestureRecognizer`
- Not adding an aux view on to `UIWindow` to add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it and then remove this view.

Thank you.

Comment: Override the vc's deallocate method and deal with the UITapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I cant. In that method I would like to remove the UITapGestureRecognizer but I dont have a strong pointer to it, so I cant do [self.view.window removeGestureRecognizer: ]...

Comment: You can just use a weak property to handle the recognizer,@property (weak, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tap in your vc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate all the gestures of UIWindow when your `viewController` is deallocated and compare the target of each of them with `self` , then remove the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

How to get the target of `UITapGestureRecognizer`, there are two solutions:

First solution: Subclass `UITapGestureRecognizer`, add a weak property named `myTarget` to keep the target and override the method `- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action`

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    [super addTarget:target action:action] ;
    _myTarget = target ;
}
```

If you use first solution, you should check if the gesture recognizer is kind of your subclass using `isKindOfClass:`.

Second solution :Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240634/getting-the-action-of-uigesturerecognizer-in-ios)

```
NSMutableArray *targets = [myGes valueForKeyPath:@"_targets"];
id targetContainer = targets[0];//get first target for example
id targetOfMyGes = [targetContainer valueForKeyPath:@"_target"];
NSLog(@"%@", targetOfMyGes );//you can see reference for target object
```