# How can I make Google maps markers activate drag on touch instead of long touch

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have looked at other posts relating to similar issues and have not seen any answers which have been helpful to solving the issue.

What I want is for the markers within my map to be draggable which they are, but, I don't want the long press.

I would like the user to simply touch a marker and have it move.

Is there some way I can do this to avoid the need for long press.

currently my code simply sets the markers to draggable so im not sure it is worth including that as this is less an issue with my current code and more of an issue of there not being an obvious solution within the sdk.

Comment: im not sure why the question has been downvoted, there are no solutions for this currently available anywhere I have looked. (with the exception of older versions for the javascript sdk) Im not sure if the solution to this issue will require a custom function for marker movement as the sdk does not seem to provide a method for alteration of the draggable method. (no other way to activate dragging with the exception of long touch)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067265/ios-google-maps-change-default-marker-dragging-behavior

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate as the question pertains to swift specifically, the question linked is out of date and no solution for my problem has been solved within the question.