# UITapGestureRecognizer not working, Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I apologize for asking this question for the millionth time, I've read the other questions asking the same thing and I couldn't find the answer to my problem!

I made a UITapGestureRecognizer that is just not working, can someone take a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
-(void) formatCellForY: (CGFloat) y{

CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat cellHeight = 70;

self.cell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Cell"]];
[self.cell setFrame:CGRectMake(20, y, screen.size.width - 40, cellHeight)];

self.cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


self.cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
self.cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
self.cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
self.cell.layer.cornerRadius = 1.0;
self.cell.clipsToBounds = NO;

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, self.cell.frame.size.width - 40, cellHeight*(.4))];
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 32;
titleLabel.text = self.program.programName;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.cell addSubview:titleLabel];

UILabel *explanationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, titleLabel.frame.origin.y + titleLabel.frame.size.height, titleLabel.frame.size.width, cellHeight - (titleLabel.frame.origin.y+ titleLabel.frame.size.height))];
explanationLabel.text = self.program.programDescription;
explanationLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
explanationLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
explanationLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
explanationLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.cell addSubview:explanationLabel];

self.tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToInfoPage:)];
self.tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
self.tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
self.tap.enabled = YES;
[self.cell addGestureRecognizer:self.tap];

NSLog(@"%@", self.tap);
}
```

Here is the code I used to add the cell to the screen.

```
for (CKRecord *record in records) {
        SBHProgram *program = [SBHProgram programForRecord:record];
        SBHCell *cell = [SBHCell cellForProgram:program andY:90*i];
        i++;
        [scrollView addSubview:cell.cell];
}
```

Comment: You've created the "cell" but have you added the "cell" to any subviews yet? I see you've added subviews to the cell.......

Comment: Yes the cell is added to the main view in the MainViewController

Comment: @Nshweky: This works on my simulator!

Comment: @Nshweky: Are you adding the cell outside the view area of its parent?

Comment: I don't think so, just a simple [self.view addSubview: obj.cell];

Comment: Can you post some more code? specifically where you are adding the cell to ur main  view? is it a separate view controller? where have you defined the above code, what class it is?

Comment: And what is the type of self.cell.

Comment: self.cell is a UIImageView, and the above code is a subclass of NSObject called SBHCell with a "cell" as one of it's properties. When I initialize the cell in the MainViewController I also add its imageView property to the view.

Comment: Could it have something to do that I'm using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ) to add the cell to the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed adding self.cell to view. You are able to see labels with texts because you have added self.cell.clipsToBounds = NO;

All you have to do is add cell to view.

**[self.view addSubview:self.cell]**

Comment: From which method are you calling formatCellForY: ?

Comment: The initializer of the class SBHCell.

Comment: It's possible that your scrollview is consuming the tap. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701323/uiscrollview-delayscontenttouches-issue delayContentTouches should solve your issue

Comment: Is it possible that it has something to do with what I'm assigning to the target to? I changed that and it started receiving the touch, just crashing when it does.

Answer (score -1):

PLEASE ADD

```
self.tap.delegate = self;
```