# UIButton inside a SwipeView isn't getting called

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, uistackview, swipeview

I have a `UIButton` instance inside a `UIStackView` as shown in the bellow view hierarchy 
I'm using [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) library.

- UIView

  - UIScrollView
  - UIStackView
  - UIView
  - UIStackView (Horizontal)

    - UILabel - UIButton

I have done everything from setting '`isExclusiveTouch`', '`delaysContentTouches`' properties to subclassing `UIScrollView` to override methods ([UIScrollview delaysContentTouches issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701323/uiscrollview-delayscontenttouches-issue)). None of this has worked out for me so far.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Adding view controller as child fixed the issue

```
func swipeView(_ swipeView: SwipeView!, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView!) -> UIView! {
let swipeView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "swipe_view") as! SwipeViewController
                swipeView.loadViewIfNeeded()
                if let stat = userInfo.stats?[index]{
                    swipeView.stat = stat
                }
                //Adding these lines fixed the issue.
                self.addChildViewController(swipeView)
                swipeView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
                return swipeView.view
                }
```

Comment: check UIStackView and UILabel's isUserInteractionEnabled property.

Comment: @YunCHEN That didn't work.

Comment: share some code relevant to button action.
and also check the IBAction of the button.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich I have connected the IBAction from Interface builder. When I tap on the button, It gets animated on the screen but the action is not called. UIButton is also a "drag and drop" from the IB.

Comment: If the button *"gets animated on the screen but the action is not called"* then the problem does **not** seem to be with touches or delays... it looks like the `IBAction` is not connected properly. That is where you need to look to find the issue.

Comment: share some code to help understanding issue. as @DonMag mentioned you need to look at your IBAction. delete and reconnect it again it may solve the problem.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich I found out the issue. There's an oversight in the code. I derived the view on Storyboard.  I forgot to add the controller as a child of parent.